# MODI gives BAD LANGUAGE error for English documents

Tags: vb.net, modi

I have been using MODI component of Office 2007 for extracting text from TIFF documents. It was working fine untill today when I executed my code it gave the error of "OCR: Bad Language"

I have not made any changes in code so in tif documents.I am scanning English documents.

> mdoc.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH,
>   True, True)

I am using VB.NET

Thanks

Comment: I have rephrase my question as well as accepted few answers

Comment: White-out the obscenities on the document prior to scanning it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the designated language pack is not installed for office.  Make sure the English language pack is installed for Office on the machine running this code.